# Is it possible to create link to user with a text which prepopulate text input field just like Whatsapp messenger do?

Tags: facebook-messenger

In Whatsapp messenger it's possible to create link to user with prepared text which appear in input text field. And user can only click Send button.

For example, this link

`https://web.whatsapp.com/send?phone=+123456789123&text=This+Is+Some+Prepared+Text`

opens Whatsapp messenger like this

[image: whatsapp screen]

Is it possible to create similar link to user in Facebook messenger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that´s not possible for Facebook, and it would not be allowed anyway. Prefilling is not allowed according to the platform policy.